# Show that $d(z_n,z)\rightarrow 0$ iff $|z_n-z_0|\rightarrow 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I solved part a.

For part b, for the forward direction I suppose $d(z_n,z)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is an integer $N$ such that $d(z_n,z)<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Now fix $n>N$. Let $x=\log C $ where $C>1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{C}\leq \frac{u(z_n)}{u(z_0)}\leq C$ for all positive harmonic $u$ on $D$.

Then, $\displaystyle \log\frac{1}{C}\leq \log(\frac{u(z_n)}{u(z_0)})\leq \log C$.

So,$\displaystyle -\log C\leq \log(\frac{u(z_n)}{u(z_0)})\leq \log C$ and hence $\displaystyle \Bigg|\log(\frac{u(z_n)}{u(z_0)})\Bigg|\leq \log C$ for all positive harmonic $u$ on $D$. After that I wanted to take a particular positive harmonic function in order to prove the result. But I was stuck. And I used a similar procedure for the backward direction and stuck at some point similar to this. Can somebody please help me?

For part c, if I use Harnack's inequality I can get that $d(0,z)\leq \log \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$. Feel like we can get hyperbolic distance, but unable to prove $d(0,z)\geq \log \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$. Any help is appreciated.